# EAN-128/GS1-128 barcode conflict

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing, gs1-ai-syntax, gs1-128

I am trying to generate EAN-128 (GS1-128) barcode labels to label a product.

I have found some online barcode generators that allow to do this task.

However, I am experiencing some conflicts between many web pages.

I mean:
for the **same code data**, two different online applicatinos generates two **different barcode images**.

Sample barcodes generated for the same data in different applications (**both are readable with my barcode scanner**):
`(01)08456789014530(15)081213`

[image]

If you check the bars, they are different.
**How can I know which is the correct generated barcode?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've disassembled the bars and spaces in each code above. There is a significant difference in the quality of the codes from an anti-aliased perspective. The bottom code is smoother and more scalable, and for that reason alone, I would select the barcode rendered on the bottom. Here is the rundown of the actual data encoded in each barcode:

```
    Top Barcode:
    Binary         Val    Code
    11010011100 == 105 == Start C 
    11110101110 == 102 == [FNC 1] 
    11110101110 == 102 == [FNC 1] 
    11001101100 == 1 == 01 GS1 (GTIN)
    10001100100 == 8 == 08 
    10111011000 == 45 == 45 
    10000101100 == 67 == 67 
    11011011110 == 89 == 89 
    11001101100 == 1 == 01 
    10111011000 == 45 == 45 
    11011011000 == 30 == 30 
    11110101110 == 102 == [FNC 1] 
    10111001100 == 15 == GS1 (BestB4Date)
    10001100100 == 8 == 08 
    10110011100 == 12 == 12 
    10011011100 == 13 == 13 
    11101100010 == 58 == Checksum 
    1100011101011 == 106 == End 

    Breaks down to [Code 128C][FNC 1][FNC 1]0108456789014530[FNC 1]15081213[Chk=58][Stop]


    Bottom Barcode
    Binary         Val    Code
    11010011100 == 105 == Start C 
    11110101110 == 102 == [FNC 1] 
    11001101100 == 1 == 01 GS1 (GTIN)
    10001100100 == 8 == 08 
    10111011000 == 45 == 45 
    10000101100 == 67 == 67 
    11011011110 == 89 == 89 
    11001101100 == 1 == 01 
    10111011000 == 45 == 45 
    11011011000 == 30 == 30 
    10111001100 == 15 == GS1 (BestB4Date)
    10001100100 == 8 == 08 
    10110011100 == 12 == 12 
    10011011100 == 13 == 13 
    11101011110 == 101 == Checksum 
    1100011101011 == 106 == End 

    Breaks down to [Code 128C][FNC 1]010845678901453015081213[Chk=101][Stop]
```

As you can see, the top barcode, while narrower, contains more data, but it is excess data (i.e. two extra [FNC 1] codes).

Comment: Wow thanks very much for that analysis. So can we say both are correct with respect to the GS1 standard?

Comment: Since they both scan, in this particular case, I suppose so. The bottom barcode seems "smarter" in the way it encodes and renders, imo.

Comment: The first barcode is simply improperly encoded. "FNC1 in second position" has a specific meaning that is unrelated to GS1 Application Identifier Syntax.